# Does casting actually DO anything?

Tags: c, casting

Consider the following snippet:

```
char x[100];
double *p = &x;
```

As expected, this yields this warning:

```
f.c:3:15: warning: initialization of ‘double *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[100]’ 
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    3 |   double *p = &x;
      |               ^
```

This is very easy to solve by just changing to

```
double *p = (double*)&x;
```

My question here is, does the casting actually DO anything? Would the code be invalid without the cast? Or is it just a way to make the compiler quiet? When is casting necessary?

I know that you can have some effect with snippets like this:

```
int x = 666;
int y = (char)x;
```

But isn't this the same as this?

```
int x = 666;
char c = x;
int y = c;
```

If it is the same, then the casting *does* something, but it's not *necessary*. Right?

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Dereferencing `p` after that assignment violates the strict alias rule, with or without the cast. So the cast silences the warning, but leaves the undefined behavior.

Comment: The conversion may do something; in some C implementations the representation of a `double *` may be different from the representation of a `char *`. The cast does something; the C standard requires a diagnostic if the types of the left and right operands of an assignment do not “match” (satisfy certain rules) but do not for a cast.

Comment: It depends on the machine, to some extent.  On the machine where I learned to program C, it made a big difference — the "pointer to `char`" value for a given physical address was different from the 'pointer to anything bigger than a `char`" value for the same address, because it was a (16-bit) word-oriented machine, and high bits were set in the address to indicate `char *` vs other pointers.  (This was in the days before gigabytes of main memory were anything other than a fantasy — we were delighted when they added 1 MiB extra memory, doubling what we had available).

Comment: The conversion between pointer types is usually mostly a no-op on modern systems.  However, if the `char *` is misaligned for the other data type, some machines may produce a 'bus error' if you try to access the `double` via the misaligned pointer.  Other machines may incur considerable overhead (system trap and code to handle the misalignment).

Comment: In the case of `int x = 666;
int y = (char)x;` it is roughly equivalent to `int y = x & 0xFF;` on most machines.  The value in `y` will not be `666` usually (unless `CHAR_BIT > 8`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But wouldn't the implicit conversion be the same in that case?

Comment: In which case, @klutt?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wouldn't `T *p; U *q = p;` be the same as `T *p; U *q = (U*)p;`? What difference would the cast do for the result? Doesn't an implicit cast take place if you omit it?

Comment: Implicit conversions between integral types have rules. The rule for pointers is that incompatible pointer assignments are not allowed.

Comment: _Doesn't an implicit cast take place if you omit it?_ No. A cast doesn't [usually] change the _value/address_ in the pointer variable. It just allows a pointer variable with type _X_ to be set from a pointer of type _Y_ [_without_ a warning/error] What you do with such an override is up to you, the programmer to ensure it does something useful/safe vs unsafe/unwise (i.e. undefined behavior)

Comment: The numeric value in `p` would probably be the same, but the cast is required by the standard to reassure the compiler that you know what you're doing.  In fact, there is no implicit conversion between most pointer types — the exception being between `void *` and `AnythingElse *`.  See C11 [§6.5.16.1 Simple assignment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1) for rules about pointer assignments.  They are horribly hard to read and understand, though.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting idea with different pointer widths due to different granularity. But: The C ISO draft 1256, 6.3.2.3/7, makes a round--trip guarantee with object pointer conversions independent of their types. So while different pointer types may in theory have different representations there must not be an information loss which in practice will result in identical representations.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Re “The C ISO draft 1256, 6.3.2.3/7, makes a round--trip guarantee with object pointer conversions independent of their types”: No, it does not. A round-trip guarantee exists only if the alignment requirement is satisfied. This means that a conversion from a laxer-alignment type to a stricter-alignment type may lose information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, good point!

Answer (score 4):

Casting can do *several* different things.  As other answers have mentioned, it almost always changes the type of the value being cast (or, perhaps, an attribute of the type, such as `const`).  It may also change the numeric value in some way.  But there are many possible interpretations:

- Sometimes it merely silences a warning, performing no "real" conversion at all (as in many pointer casts).
- Sometimes it silences a warning, leaving only a type change but no value change (as in other pointer casts).
- Sometimes the type change, although it involves no obvious value change, implies *very* different semantics for use of the value later (again, as in many pointer casts).
- Sometimes it requests a conversion which is meaningless or impossible.
- Sometimes it performs a conversion that the compiler would have performed by itself (with or without a warning).
- But sometimes it forces a conversion that the compiler wouldn't have performed.

Also, sometimes those warnings that the compiler tried to make, that a cast silences, are innocuous and/or a nuisance, but sometimes they're quite real, and the code is likely to fail (that is, as the silenced warning was trying to tell you).

For some more specific examples:

A pointer cast that changes the type, but not the value:

```
char *p1 = ... ;
const char *p2 = (const char *)p;
```

And another:

```
unsigned char *p3 = (unsigned char *)p;
```

A pointer cast that changes the type in a more significant way, but that's guaranteed to be okay (on some architectures this might also change the value):

```
int i;
int *ip = &i;
char *p = (char *)ip;
```

A similarly significant pointer cast, but one that's quite likely to be *not* okay:

```
char c;
char *cp = &c;
int *ip = (int *)cp;
*ip = 5;                  /* likely to fail */
```

A pointer cast that's so meaningless that the compiler refuses to perform it, even with an explicit cast:

```
float f = 3.14;
char *p = (char)f;        /* guaranteed to fail */
```

A pointer cast that makes a conversion, but one that the compiler would have made anyway:

```
int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

(This one is considered a bad idea, because in the case where you forget to include `<stdlib.h>` to declare `malloc()`, the cast can silence a warning that might alert you to the problem.)

Three casts from an integer to a pointer, that are actually well-defined, due to a *very* specific special case in the C language:

```
void *p1 = (void *)0;
char *p2 = (void *)0;
int *p3 = (int *)0;
```

Two casts from integer to pointer that are not necessarily valid, although the compiler will generally do something obvious, and the cast will silence the otherwise warning:

```
int i = 123;
char *p1 = (char *)i;
char *p2 = (char *)124;
*p1 = 5;                  /* very likely to fail, except when */
*p2 = 7;                  /* doing embedded or OS programming */
```

A *very* questionable cast from a pointer back to an `int`:

```
char *p = ... ;
int i = (int)p;
```

A less-questionable cast from a pointer back to an integer that ought to be big enough:

```
char *p = ... ;
uintptr_t i = (uintptr_t)p;
```

A cast that changes the type, but "throws away" rather than "converting" a value, and that silences a warning:

```
(void)5;
```

A cast that makes a numeric conversion, but one that the compiler would have made anyway:

```
float f = (float)0;
```

A cast that changes the type and the interpreted value, although it typically won't change the bit pattern:

```
short int si = -32760;
unsigned short us = (unsigned short)si;
```

A cast that makes a numeric conversion, but one that the compiler probably would have warned about:

```
int i = (int)1.5;
```

A cast that makes a conversion that the compiler would *not* have made:

```
double third = (double)1 / 3;
```

The bottom line is that casts definitely do things: some of them useful, some of them unnecessary but innocuous, some of them dangerous.

These days, the consensus among many C programmers is that most casts are or should be unnecessary, meaning that it's a decent rule to avoid explicit casts unless you're sure you know what you're doing, and it's reasonable to be suspicious of explicit casts you find in someone else's code, since they're likely to be a sign of trouble.

---

As one final example, this was the case that, back in the day, really made the light bulb go on for me with respect to pointer casts:

```
char *loc;
int val;
int size;

/* ... */

switch(size) {
    case 1: *loc += val; break;
    case 2: *(int16_t *)loc += val; break;
    case 4: *(int32_t *)loc += val; break;
}
```

Those three instances of `loc += val` do three pretty different things: one updates a byte, one updates a 16-bit int, and one updates a 32-bit int.  (The code in question was a dynamic linker, performing symbol relocation.)

Comment: The latter only with pointers, right? I.e. point 2.

Comment: Nice. Would be good if you provided examples for each.

Comment: Also, the warnings in point 2 are probably exclusively for cases which potentially change the value, like narrowing conversions  (hence the warning).

Comment: @klutt Absolutely, but it took a while until I had time to add some.

Answer (score 3):

The cast does at least 1 thing - it satisfies the following constraint on assignment:

> **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**
> **Constraints**
> 1    One of the following shall hold:<sup>112)</sup>
> ...
> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
> the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) ***both operands are
> pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types***, and the type pointed
> to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
>
> ---
>
> <sup>112) The asymmetric appearance of these constraints with respect to type qualifiers is due to the conversion
> (specified in 6.3.2.1) that changes lvalues to ‘‘the value of the expression’’ and thus removes any type
> qualifiers that were applied to the type category of the expression (for example, it removes **`const`** but
> not **`volatile`** from the type **`int volatile * const`**).</sup>

That's a *compile-time* constraint - it affects whether or not the source code is translated to an executable, but it doesn't necessarily affect the translated machine code.

It *may* result in an actual conversion being performed at runtime, but that depends on the types involved in the expression and the host system.

Answer (score 2):

Casting changes the type, which can be very important when signed or unsigned type matters,

For example, character handling functions such as `isupper()` are [defined as taking an `unsigned char` value or `EOF`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1):

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Thus code such as

```
int isNumber( const char *input )
{
    while ( *input )
    {
        if ( !isdigit( *input ) )
        {
             return( 0 );
        }
        input++;
    }
    // all digits
    return( 1 );
}
```

should properly cast the `const char`  value of `*input` to `unsigned char`:

```
int isNumber( const char *input )
{
    while ( *input )
    {
        if ( !isdigit( ( unsigned char ) *input ) )
        {
             return( 0 );
        }
        input++;
    }
    // all digits
    return( 1 );
}
```

Without the cast to `unsigned char`, when `*input` is promoted to `int`, an `char` value (assuming `char` is signed and smaller than `int`) that is negative will be sign-extended to a negative value that can *not* be represented as an `unsigned char` value and therefore invoke undefined behavior.

So yes, the cast in this case does something.  It changes the type and therefore - on almost all current systems - avoids undefined behavior for input `char` values that are negative.

There are also cases where `float` values can be cast to `double` (or the reverse) to force code to behave in a desired manner.*

* - I've seen such cases recently - if someone can find an example, feel free to add your own answer...

Comment: More importantly, the cast to unsigned char potentially *changes the value.* The issue is not one of type -- all character types will be converted (promoted?) to int just fine. The issue is that the value  of a plain `char` may be negative which is forbidden.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Indeed, it's the *value* that gets passed to `isdigit()` that's important in my example here.

Comment: Which is why the statement "Casting changes the type, which can be very important ..." is wrong in this context. The type is irrelevant. You can pass bools, _uint128 or long doubles if you like.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica *The type is irrelevant.*  No, it's not in this case because the binary values in the resulting `int` can differ depending on the type of `char` passed - `signed` or `unsigned`.  If a *signed* `char` is negative and promoted to match the `int` argument of `isdigit()`, it will be sign-extended to a value that is not representable as an `unsigned char` (on almost all systems...) and therefore invoke undefined behavior.  The cast is critical in changing the type to avoid the sign extension here because of the standard's restriction on allowable values.

Comment: Yes, obviously the resulting values in the `int` can change -- but those values do not depend on the type of the argument! The argument can -- as I said before -- have *any* numeric type. The point is that it must have a *value* which can be represented in an `unsigned char`. How you have arrived there doesn't matter; most certainly you don't need an unsigned char or a cast (you could simply compute the positive value with the same bit pattern as the negative byte with an if/else chain and assign it to an `int` argument, for example). **The type really does not matter. The value does.**

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica *those values do not depend on the type of the argument!* Yes, it does. When a twos-complement `unsigned char` value of `0xF4` gets promoted it `int`, it's not sign extended and the resulting `int` value is `0x000000F4`, assuming a 32-bit `int`.  When a twos-complement `signed char` value of `0xF4` is promoted to `int`, it's sign extended and gets promoted to `0xFFFFFFF4`, which is not representable as an `unsigned char` and therefore invokes undefined behavior when passed to `isdigit()`.

Comment: All you say is correct, and I am fully aware of it. But reconsider the signature of `int isdigit(int)`: It certainly does not expect an unsigned char, or a char. It *does* expect **any numeric value** that is within the value range of an `unsigned char`. A signed char with the bit pattern f4  is an integer value of -12 and is thus not permissible. Casting it to an `unsigned char` **changes the value**: It is now an integer value of 244. How you arrive at 244 is irrelevant (casting is just a way to preserve the bit pattern f4). What type the expression with that value has is irrelevant as well.

Answer (score 2):

The cast may or may not change the actual binary value. But that is *not* its main purpose, just a side effect.

It tells the compiler to interpret a value as a value of a different type. Any changing of binary value is a side effect of that.

It is for you (the programmer) to let the compiler know: I know what I'm doing. So you can shoot yourself in the foot without the compiler questioning you.

Don't get me wrong, cast are absolutely necessary in real world code, but they must be used with care and knowledge. Never cast just to get rid of a warning, make sure you understand the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible that a system would use a different representation for a `void *` and a `char *` than for some other pointer type. The possibility exists that there could be a system that normally uses a narrow width register to hold pointer values. But, the narrow width may be insufficient if the code needed to address every single byte, and so a `void *` or `char *` would use a wider representation.

One case where casting a pointer value is useful is when the function takes a variable number of pointer arguments, and is terminated by NULL, such as with the `execl()` family of functions.

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "echo Hello world!", (char *)NULL);
```

Without the cast, the `NULL` may expand to `0`, which would be treated as an `int` argument. When the `execl()` function retrieves the last parameter, it may extract the expected pointer value incorrectly, since an `int` value was passed.

Answer (score 1):

> My question here is, does the casting actually DO anything?

**Yes.** It tells the compiler, and also other programmers including the future you, that you think you know what you're doing and you really do intend to treat a `char` as an `int` or whatever. It may or may not change the compiled code.

> Would the code be invalid without the cast?

That depends on the cast in question. One example that jumps to mind involves division:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
float c = a / b;
```

Questions about this sort of thing come up all the time on SO: people wonder why `c` gets a value of 0. The answer, of course, is that both `a` and `b` are `int`, and the result of integer division is also an integer that's only converted to a `float` upon assignment to `c`. To get the expected value of 0.6 in `c`, cast `a` or `b` to `float`:

```
float c = a / (float)b;
```

You might not consider the code without the cast to be *invalid*, but the next computation might involve division by `c`, at which point a division by zero error could occur without the cast above.

> Or is it just a way to make the compiler quiet?

Even if the cast is a no-op in terms of changing the compiled code, preventing the compiler from complaining about a type mismatch is doing *something*.

> When is casting necessary?

It's *necessary* when it changes the object code that the compiler generates. It might also be *necessary* if your organization's coding standards require it.

Comment: But in the float case, we could - as I did in my last example - just as well use a temp, right? `float tmp = b; float c = a / tmp;`

Comment: @klutt Sure, and then you're explicitly doing what the compiler does when you cast `b` to `float`. By *necessary* do you mean *Is there anything you can do with a cast that you can't do some other way?*? I'd imagine that there isn't -- whatever a given cast does, you can probably do the same thing explicitly yourself just as with your temporary variable. But that's like claiming that integer multiplication isn't necessary because you can do the same thing with a `for` loop and addition.

Comment: With necessary I use the vague definition of "Is there anything you can do with a cast that you can't do some other way, *within reason*". Your example with the for loop is - according to my definition - unreasonably clunky.

Comment: @klutt Your temporary variable is arguably just another way to cast `b` to `float`. In my example, the cast doesn't actually change `b` into a float; `b` remains an `int` after the cast. The cast changes the value used in the calculation to a `float`. Doing it explicitly with the temporary variable is the same thing with different syntax. The casting operation is necessary, whether you express it with a temporary variable or with casting syntax.

Answer (score 1):

An example where cast makes a difference.

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long x = 1 << 33,y = (unsigned long long)1 << 33;

    printf("%llx, %llx\n", x, y);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b3qcPn

Comment: But you could just as well do `unsigned long long y = 1UUL << 33` right?

Comment: @klutt Great, I am happy to know that you know it. Good job.

Comment: I'm actually unsure if you're sarcastic or not. :D

Comment: @klutt BTW it is not `1UUL << 33` only `1ULL << 33`

Comment: That's true. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

A cast is simply a *type conversion*: The implementation will represent the argument value by means of the target type. The expression of the new type (let's assume the target type is different) may have

- a different size
- a different value
- and/or a different bit pattern representing the value.

These three changes are orthogonal to each other. Any subset, including none and all of them, can occur (all examples assume two's bit complement):

- None of them: `(unsigned int)1;`
- Size only: `(char)1`
- Value only: `(unsigned int)-1`
- Bit pattern only: `(float)1` (my machine has sizeof(int) == sizeof(float))
- Size and value, but not bit pattern (the bits present in the original value): `(unsigned int)(char)-4`
- Size and bit pattern, but not value: `(float)1l`
- value and bit pattern, but not size: `(float)1234567890)` (32 bit ints and floats)
- All of them: `(float)1234567890l` (long is 64 bits).

The new type may, of course, influence expressions in which it is used, and will often have different text representations (e.g. via printf), but that's not really surprising.

Pointer conversions may deserve a little more discussion: The new pointer typically has the same value, size and bit representation (although, as Eric Postpischli correctly pointed out, it theoretically may not). The main intent and effect of a pointer cast is not to change the pointer; it is to change the semantics of the memory accessed through it.

In some cases a cast is the only means to perform a conversion (non-compatible pointer types, pointer vs. integer).

In other cases like narrowing arithmetic conversions (which may lose information or produce an overflow) a cast indicates intent and thus silences warnings. In all cases where a conversion could also be implicitly performed the cast does not alter the program's behavior — it is optional decoration.