# What type casting address, when assigning to pointer, does?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm working on understanding C and I came across this example:

```
int main()
{
    double d = 010;
    unsigned *pi = (unsigned *) &d;
    printf("%x", *++pi);
}
```

So `d` has value of 8 in decimal numerical system, 0 10000000010 000... in binary and 40200000 in hexadecimal. I don't understand what this typecast of address does. Why doesn't `*pi` get hexadecimal value, but instead it prints 0? When it's address is incremented and then dereferenced it get's right hexadecimal value. Why?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: This code prints out 40200000 and I understand that number, but it confuses me why address has to be incremented.

Comment: Probably a dup of this one [Does casting actually DO anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66001033/6699433)

Comment: Or it can be something with endianess

Comment: `(unsigned *) &d` is undefined behavior. These aren't compatible types and it's a strict aliasing violation to de-reference the value through the wrong type. Generally, casts in C aren't guaranteed to be safe and predictable at all. Avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: Regarding why the address increment is needed specifically, see [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640). Then find out what floating point representation that's used by your system to understand how the double is stored.

Comment: Do you overcomplicate the problem on purpose to test us?  Vote to close, sorry.  Your program has around thirteen undefined behaviours simultaneously, so what do you want from it?

Comment: Please, when using `double` variables, use also floating point literals (why did you inicialize `d` using an octal integer literal instead of `8.0`, which requires no conversions to overcomplicate things?)  Your question looks like a test to prove our skils more than a question on a problem you have.

Comment: This was question on my exam, so I'm practicing. I have no intention on testing anybody's skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code actually has undefined behavior because of the aliasing rule: you are accessing the representation of the `double` variable with a pointer to another type that is not a character type.

The intent is to print the 32-bits from the bytes 4 to 7 of the `double` variable, which are all `0` because of the way `8.0` is represented on your architecture.

The cast tells the compiler to convert the pointer to another type of pointer. This usually does not change its value, but dereferencing the resulting pointer may produce undefined behavior, except for character types.

Here is a modified version that is portable and prints the byte values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double d = 010;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)&d;
    int n = sizeof(double);

    while (n --> 0) {
        printf("%02x ", *p++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output on an Intel Mac (little endian): `00 00 00 00 00 00 20 40`

Output on a big-endian system: `40 20 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Comment: Was just about to write an answer myself, but this is basically what I was about to write.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I get what's going on now. So `p` points to 00 assuming it's LE and it counts by 4, because that's size of unsigned int. When you increment it, it simply goes to next address and checks those other 4 bytes.

Comment: to be more pricese format shuld be `%02hhxx`

Comment: @0___________: not necessary (even without the extra `x`) as types shorter than `int` are promoted to `int` when passed to vararg functions and `int` values can be passed for `unsigned int` formats when the value is in the range of `unsigned int`. C17 7.21.6.1 describes `hh` as: *Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); [...]*

Comment: @0___________: printing the value as a `signed char` would require either `printf("%d ", (signed char)*p++)` or `printf("%hhd ", *p++)`.  If `p` had type `char *`, then it would be a good idea to use `printf("%02hhx ", *p++)` as suggested because the `char` value could be negative on some platforms and produce more than 2 hex digits without the `hh`.